# Can't find suitable Main method

Tags: c#, .net, class, compiler-construction, codedom

I'm trying to create a Windows Form Application, that can create another Windows Form Application. But the error i'm getting when i'm trying to compile with CodeDom in the c# code, is a weird one.

```
'kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.RunLauncher' does not have a suitable static Main method
```

This kinda confuses me, since the class "RunLauncher" DOES have a main method, with the default setup described at the (http://msdn.microsoft.com/) site.

**RunLauncher class:** http://pastebin.com/NU3VYwpv (which have the main method)

The code i'm using to actually compile this via. CodeDom is this:

```
if (codeProvider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.EntryPointMethod))
{
    parameters.MainClass = "kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.RunLauncher";
}

CodeCompileUnit compileUnits = new CodeCompileUnit();
CodeNamespace nsp = new CodeNamespace("kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate");

parameters.CompilerOptions = "/main:kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.RunLauncher";

CodeTypeDeclaration class1 = new CodeTypeDeclaration("RunLauncher");
nsp.Types.Add(class1);

CodeTypeDeclaration class2 = new CodeTypeDeclaration("kjpUnityGameLauncher");
nsp.Types.Add(class2);

CodeTypeDeclaration class3 = new CodeTypeDeclaration("Launcher");
nsp.Types.Add(class3);

nsp.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate"));
compileUnits.Namespaces.Add(nsp);
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnits);
```

Theres some other stuff like declaration of the variables "codeProvider" etc. but those aren't the problem in this case, which is why I didn't include them.

Comment: I'm presuming this is your first C# Windows Forms App?

Comment: Show us your generated source, or the code the generates the `Main()` method.

Comment: No, the windows form application to compile the new windows form application as a new .exe works. It's just the section where I click a button on the first app, to use the "compile code" above, and use the new Main Class, for the new application. So I basicly have 2 Main classes, one that only affects the generated one through code.

Comment: I did link the class, to which does have the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create an Executable Your code must have an Entry Point Method declared and **set** properly to run in CodeDom. I do not see one declared in your example above. Below I have an example from MSDN located at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx

```
CodeEntryPointMethod start = new CodeEntryPointMethod();
CodeMethodInvokeExpression cs1 = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Console"),
"WriteLine", new CodePrimitiveExpression("Hello World!"));
start.Statements.Add(cs1);
```

Comment: I see, but isn't there a more "automated" way of writing the main class, into this? Instead of I having to write alot of CodeMethodInvokeExpressions.

Could you possible, give me an example of this, with my example above?